Прямое TCP подключение через JS на стороне браузера
Нужно через сайт сделать прямое tcp соединение с сервером. Я пробовал использовать WebSocket,  но он работает не на чистом tcp а на http. Я дошел только до того что при попытке подключения на мой tcp сокет на сервере приходит
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:900
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/125.0.0.0
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: sigRmsd5TGWhrFH3NPJt0w==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

и на сколько я понял пока мой сервак на это не ответит, коннект не произойдет.
Мне нужно принимать относительно много данных и желательно именно необработанный массив байтов который я отправляю. Возможно ли это реализовать на WebSocket? Если нет то как можно реализовать потоковую передачу данных с клиентом через JS?

Из JS нельзя создать произвольное TCP-соединение. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

@AlexeyTen мне нужно передавать множество координат в потоковом режиме

А чем вам WebSockets API не угодил? Или вот ещё есть Streams API и WebTransport.

В том же веб-сокете соединение устанавливается один раз, а потом можете слать свои миллионы сообщений через это соединение.

Вот проимер с описанием создания сокета - там есть ссылка на репозиторий с кодом

Ну да, ваш сервер должен ответить на этот запрос. И после этого установится соединение и все ваши координаты будут отправляться по этому уже установленному соединению. Т.е. этот «большой» запрос случается только один раз.

@AlexeyTen я видел этот гайд, но я попробовал написать небольшой сервер на c#, и после подключения я отправлял HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=\r\n но все равно соединение не происходило

Это уже не проблема вебсокетов. Пример сервера на C# есть даже на MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

@AlexeyTen, действительно, что то сделал и что то заработало, наконец то получилось принять сообщение, только у него что то с кодировкой, ну это уже не так страшно кажется

Зачем писать свой вебсокет-сервер, если есть куча готовых https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-8.0
